# Best way to implement authenticated routing in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There is a public and private part of the app. An unauthenticated user shouldn't have access to the content rendered on private routes, and instead be presented with an error page.

The user should also be presented with an error page when trying to access a non existing route. This error page needs to be rendered as a child component to either LandingLayout or AppLayout, depending on the auth state, which is why I am not using the errorElement prop.

Here is the *index.jsx* where the **router** paths are defined:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
    path: "/",
    element: <ProtectedRouting UnAuthElement={<LandingLayout />} AuthElement={<AppLayout />} />,
    children: [
        { path: "/", element: <ProtectedRouting UnAuthElement={<LandingPage />} AuthElement={<PrivateHome />} /> },
        { path: "/createEvent", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<CreateEvent />} /> },
        { path: "/events", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<EventsPage />} /> },
        { path: "/contacts", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<ContactsPage />} /> },
        { path: "/notifications", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<Notifications />} /> },
        { path: "/weather", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<WeatherPage />} /> },
        {
            path: "/events/:eventId",
            element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<SingleEventPage />} />,
        },
        { path: "/views", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<ViewsPage />} /> },
        { path: "/views/upload", element: <ProtectedRouting AuthElement={<UploadPhoto />} /> },
        {
            path: "/*",
            element: (
                <ErrorPage
                    title="Resource not found"
                    message="Make sure to enter a valid URL"
                />
            ),
        },
    ],
},
```

]);

Here is the *ProtectedRouting* component:

```
export const ProtectedRouting = ({
    UnAuthElement = <ErrorPage message="You must be logged in to access this page!" />,
    AuthElement,
}) => {
    const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

    if (loading) {
        return <CustomSpinner />;
    }

    return user ? AuthElement : UnAuthElement;
};
```

This is the solution I came up with, and **it works**, but I am sure it can be improved, and probably simplified. I just couldn't find any resources that were suited to my case.